# What is the origin of the term “Telescoping Series”?

Tags: mathematics

I looked into Carl. B. Boyer and Morris Kline books of math history, some calculus books like Apostol and Swokowski, many pages on the internet and even the Tractatus de Seriebus Infinitis of Jacobi Bernoulli with no sucess to find out the origin of the term "Telescoping Series".

On Math Exchange Sammy Black explained the meaning, but I still have no reference to the history of the term.

May someone help?

Comment: The earliest instances of the term "telescoping series" in the mathematical sense that I could find with a quick search on Google Books date to 1936 and 1945 respectively. The term *may* have entered the English literature as a loanword from another language; if so, German or French are the most likely candidates.

Comment: The term doesn't seem to be an import from German, because the earliest mention of "Teleskopreihe" I could find dates to 1965.

Comment: @njuffa could you please send me the 1936 and 1945 references? I also thank you.

Comment: [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22telescoping+series%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C44&as_ylo=&as_yhi=1950) brings up the same items.

Comment: The trick, but not the term, goes back at least to Johann Bernoulli c. 1689, see [Bibiloni et al., On a Series of Goldbach and Euler](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2006.11920299).